# Can anyone help me with the R packages EcoSimR and bipartite?

Tags: r, package, bipartite

I'm trying to use these packages to niche analysis but both seems to be removed from CRAN and packages which should replace them are not working. There is a new source for these packages or any way to carry out this analysis using another package?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

- Here you can download the archived file:

https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/EcoSimR/

- Save the `EcoSimR_0.1.0.tar` to your folder.
- Got to Packages in RStudio and press install

[image]

- Install from archive

[image]